# Adding number for each linear feature group by type using PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a linear layer with line type A,B,C (red,green,blue). For each linear feature I added MANUALLY sequence numbers (for line with name `A: 1,2,3,4,5`; for line with name `B: 1,2,3`; for line with name `C: 1,2,3,4`).

How can I add sequence numbers automatically with saving sequence in line direction (from start to end line)?

[image]

I tried the next SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS route_lines_test;
CREATE TABLE route_lines_test AS
SELECT
t.geom,
t."name",
t."order",
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t."name" ORDER BY ST_X(ST_Centroid(t.geom))) AS order_sql
FROM
(
SELECT
geom,
gid,
"name",
"order"
FROM
line_layer
ORDER BY "name", ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom))
) t
```

where I added line ordering by line centroid 'X' coordinate, but received incorrect result for line 'B' (green)

[image]

Comment: Add feature number where?

Comment: Add number for each linear feature - red:1,2,3,4; green: 1,2,3

Comment: Postgis is not a drawing app. Each geometry is a single entity, so you can't add numbers to line segments, as such. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Are we talking about numbering line **features** or line **segments** ? Your drawing is all but clear indeed ... what do u call "add number" : you want to associate a number following which logic ? or is your need only a **display** issue in QGIS for example ?

Comment: @JohnPowell I added updates

Comment: @snaileater I added updates

Comment: the ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom) of the upper part of the green line, lies between 1 and 3.  Your SQL is right!

Comment: @PieterB yes, this is works if line horizontal but fail if line have 'S' shape (or as green line; not horizontal). But on the example above for green line I received sequence 1-3-2 (not 1-2-3)

Comment: that's because the upper part lies more to the left then the middle part.  So the x-coordinate of that part comes first if you order by ST_X(ST_Centroid(geom)) !